# Python append string to bytearray and receive string from bytearray

Tags: python, sockets

I am making an IoT device that calculates the pressure, water flow and gets the coordinates of the device. I am using python socket. I need to send them to the web application. However, I always got this output:

Connected by: (ip_address, port)

> > 49 46

This is my code to send to the web:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = 'my_ip'
PORT = myPort

#Temp storage
pressure = "1.6"
waterflow = "2.6"
latitude = "08.123"
longitude = "124.336"

my_bytes = bytearray()

my_bytes.extend(pressure.encode('latin-1'))
my_bytes.extend(waterflow.encode('latin-1'))
my_bytes.extend(latitude.encode('latin-1'))
my_bytes.extend(longitude.encode('latin-1'))

#Ready to pass data to web
information = [pressure, waterflow, latitude, longitude]

#Open Connection and Establish
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(my_bytes)
```

and this is the code that receives data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket

host = 'myHost'
port = myport

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    with conn:
            print('Connected by: ', addr)
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                my_bytes = bytearray(data)
                print(my_bytes[0], my_bytes[1])
                break
```

Expected output

> > 1.6 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to check out the Python [array](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html) module for storing efficient arrays of numeric values.

I reworked your code to use this module instead of `bytearray`. Your storage variables are now floats (instead of strings) and are transmitted over the network as such. Using floats will be more memory-efficient than strings for higher precisions.

```py
import socket
import array

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 55000

#Temp storage
pressure = 1.6
waterflow = 2.6
latitude = 8.123
longitude = 124.336

information = [pressure, waterflow, latitude, longitude]
my_bytes = array.array('f', information)  # 'f' = float

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(my_bytes)
```

And the receiver:

```py
import socket
import array

host = 'localhost'
port = 55000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    with conn:
        print('Connected by: ', addr)
        data = conn.recv(1024)  # blocking
        my_bytes = array.array('f', data)
        information = my_bytes.tolist()
        print(information)
```

I removed the `while` loop in the receiver for the purposes of this demo since `conn.recv()` is a blocking call.